# Adding admin top-level menus

Tags: admin-menu

I am writing a plugin ([Github Link](https://github.com/uncovery/unc_gallery)) and have trouble setting up the titles of the admin menu.

I defined a top header menu with add_menu_page ([link to code, same as below](https://github.com/uncovery/unc_gallery/blob/master/unc_backend.inc.php#L17)) and 2 children with add_submenu_page, but I get 4 lines in the Admin menu, the main one, then that one again (with the same link target) in small and then the 2 children.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'unc_gallery_admin_menu');
function unc_gallery_admin_menu() {
    // the main page where we manage the options
    add_menu_page(
        'Uncovery Gallery Options', // $page_title,
        'Uncovery Gallery', // $menu_title,
        'manage_options', // $capability,
        'unc_gallery_admin_menu', // $menu_slug,
        'unc_gallery_options' // $function, $icon_url, $position
    );
    // where we upload images
    $upload_page_hook_suffix = add_submenu_page(
        'unc_gallery_admin_menu', // $parent_slug
        'Upload Images',  // $page_title
        'Upload Images', // $menu_title
        'manage_options', // capability, manage_options is the default
        'unc_gallery_admin_upload', // menu_slug
        'unc_uploads_form' // function
    );
    add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $upload_page_hook_suffix, 'unc_gallery_admin_add_css_and_js');
    // where we list up all the images
    $view_page_hook_suffix = add_submenu_page(
        'unc_gallery_admin_menu', // $parent_slug
        'View Images',  // $page_title
        'View Images', // $menu_title
        'manage_options', // capability, manage_options is the default
        'unc_gallery_admin_view', // menu_slug
        'unc_gallery_admin_display_images' // function
    );
    add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $view_page_hook_suffix, 'unc_gallery_admin_add_css_and_js');    
}
```

[image]

How can I either change the title of the 2nd "Uncovery Gallery" or preferably remove it?

thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant code to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the first Submenu text with the following script:

```
function __test_menu() {
    global $submenu;
    //var_dump($submenu); //check yourself
    $submenu['unc_gallery_admin_menu'][0][0] = __( 'Test', 'textdomain' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', '__test_menu' );
```

Please note, your plugin is error-prone, throwing warning messages. Always develop things with `WP_DEBUG` to `true`. And don't write hardcore texts, better write them in [gettext functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers). i.e. write `__( 'Test', 'textdomain' );` instead of `'Test';`. It will make your plugin translation-ready. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, found the 2 warnings and fixed them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use.

```
 add_submenu_page('unc_gallery_admin_menu', '', '', 'read','unc_gallery_admin_menu', 'unc_gallery_options');
```